# Charge connected stripe account

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm using Stripe API and Stripe Connect. I want to transfer money from Customers to Express Connected account. I want to use [direct](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) charges, but it's not clear from the docs, how should I use it. The documentation says:

```
To directly charge on the connected account, perform a standard 
create charge request using your platform’s secret key while 
authenticated as the connected account:

curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u {STRIPE_SECRET_TOKEN}: \
   -d amount=1000 \
   -d currency=usd \
   -d source=tok_visa \
   -H "Stripe-Account: {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}"
```

As far as I understand, that means that connected account will be charged. However the documentation doesn't say how can I move to the connected account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this request would [charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) the customer's payment source (represented by the token in the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-source) parameter -- in this example, it's a static [test token](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards), but in a live integration you'd generate a token from the customer's card using [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements)), and the funds would be sent to the connected account specified in the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header.

If you wish to take a cut out of this transaction, you'd need to add an [`application_fee`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-application_fee) parameter. The funds would then automatically be split when creating the charge, with the application fee being added to your platform's balance and the remainder (charge amount minus your application fee and Stripe's own fees) being added to the connected account's balance.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really got confused by `To directly charge on the connected account` phrase

Comment: @Ywain, I have more doubts in it are you available to explan?